Using fresh cookies from catch Error in HttpIntercopterFn
I have created an interceptor to ensure that every request sends HttpOnly JWT/refresh tokens. I am attempting to refresh my short-lived JWT by catching a 401 error and asking the server for a refresh. It seems to be working, though perhaps not as I expect.
This is my code:
export const jwtInterceptor: HttpInterceptorFn = (req, next) => {
  const router: Router = inject(Router);
  const authService: AuthService = inject(AuthService);

  req = req.clone({
    withCredentials: true,
  });

  return next(req).pipe(
    catchError((err: any) => {
      if (err instanceof HttpErrorResponse) {
        // Handle HTTP errors
        if (err.status === 401) {
          // handle unauthorized errors
          console.error('Unauthorized request:', err);
          // retry the request
          authService.refreshToken().subscribe({
            next: () => {
              authService.isRefreshed$.next(true);
            },
            error: () => {
              // Redirect to login page
              authService.logout(true);
              return router.createUrlTree(['/login'], {
                queryParams: { returnUrl: router.url },
              });
            },
          });
          return authService.isRefreshed$.pipe(switchMap(() => next(req)));
        } else {
          // Handle other HTTP error codes
          console.error('HTTP error:', err);
        }
      } else {
        // Handle non-HTTP errors
        console.error('An error occurred:', err);
      }
      // Re-throw the error to propagate it further
      return throwError(() => err);
    })
  );
};

When I look at the network calls through developer tools, they seem to be made in the order I expect. The cookie is refreshed successfully but is not being used in the retried request.
I cannot modify the request with the HttpOnly cookie through TS, so I'm unsure how to proceed.
The goal is to retry the failed request with the refreshed cookie. In the future, I will think about caching multiple requests and retrying them in a queue.
Update 1:
Changes made using suggestions from Naren:
const handle401Error = (
    isRefreshing: boolean,
    req: HttpRequest<any>,
    next: HttpHandlerFn
  ) => {
    if (!isRefreshing) {
      isRefreshing = true;
      // issue described below was resolved with the return statement
      return authService.refreshToken().pipe(  
        switchMap(() => {                
          isRefreshing = false;
          console.log('Token refreshed successfully.');
          return next(req);
        }),
        catchError((err) => {
          isRefreshing = false;
          console.error('Error refreshing token:', err);
          authService.logout();
          router.navigate(['/login'], { queryParams: { returnUrl: req.url } });
          return throwError(() => err);
        })
      );
    }
    return next(req);
  };

I am calling handle401error when if (err.status == 401)
But the above code does not ever make the refresh API call. I suspect the call is canceled as return next(req) at the end of handle401error is canceling the refresh request. authService.refreshToken() has a log instruction so I know it is being entered. But neither the switchMap() nor the catchError() are executed in handle401error.
Update 2:
The final code I have settled on is below. Although failing calls can still be made while the token is refreshing, further attempts to refresh the tokens do not occur and all failed calls are retried.
let refreshTokenInProgress$: Subject<boolean> | null = null;

export const jwtInterceptor: HttpInterceptorFn = (req, next) => {
  const router: Router = inject(Router);
  const authService: AuthService = inject(AuthService);
  req = req.clone({
    withCredentials: true,
  });

  // if token is refreshing wait for it to complete before making the request
  const handle401error = () => {
    if (!refreshTokenInProgress$) {
      refreshTokenInProgress$ = new Subject<boolean>();
      authService.refreshToken().subscribe({
        next: () => {
          refreshTokenInProgress$!.next(true);
        },
        error: () => {
          refreshTokenInProgress$!.next(false);
          authService.logout();
          router.navigate(['/login']);
        },
        complete: () => {
          refreshTokenInProgress$!.complete();
          refreshTokenInProgress$ = null;
        },
      });
    }
  };

  return next(req).pipe(
    catchError((err: any) => {
      if (err instanceof HttpErrorResponse) {
        if (err.status === 401) {
          handle401error();
          return refreshTokenInProgress$!.pipe(switchMap(() => next(req)));
        }
      }
      return throwError(() => err);
    })
  );
};


Revised Approach
=> Return the Observable: authService.refreshToken() should return an observable that emits after the token is refreshed. This allows handle401Error to complete only after the refresh is done.
=> Use a Subject for the Refresh Process: A Subject can manage multiple calls that encounter a 401 error while the token is refreshing. This will help avoid race conditions or duplicate refresh attempts if multiple requests fail simultaneously.
  import { Subject, throwError } from 'rxjs';
  import { switchMap, catchError, filter, take, tap } from 'rxjs/operators';

  let isRefreshing = false;
  const refreshSubject = new Subject<boolean>();

  const handle401Error = (
    req: HttpRequest<any>,
    next: HttpHandlerFn
  ) => {
    if (!isRefreshing) {
      isRefreshing = true;
      authService.refreshToken().pipe(
        tap(() => {
          isRefreshing = false;
          refreshSubject.next(true);  // Notify others waiting for the refresh
        }),
        catchError((err) => {
          isRefreshing = false;
          refreshSubject.next(false);  // Notify failure
          authService.logout();
          router.navigate(['/login'], { queryParams: { returnUrl: req.url } });
          return throwError(() => err);
        })
      ).subscribe();
    }

    // Wait for the refresh to complete
    return refreshSubject.pipe(
      filter(isRefreshed => isRefreshed),  // Proceed only if refresh succeeded
      take(1),  // Only take the first successful refresh event
      switchMap(() => next(req))
    );
  };

  // In the interceptor catchError block:
  return next(req).pipe(
    catchError((err: any) => {
      if (err instanceof HttpErrorResponse && err.status === 401) {
        return handle401Error(req, next);
      }
      return throwError(() => err);
    })
  );

Explanation

isRefreshing flag: Ensures that only one refresh attempt is made at a
time.
refreshSubject: Queues any incoming requests while a refresh is
ongoing. It only allows requests to proceed when the token is
refreshed (emits true) or an error occurs (emits false).
filter and take: Ensures that requests waiting on a refresh only proceed once it’s completed and successful.

Notes
This approach should ensure the refreshed token is in place for subsequent retries.
For the request queuing functionality you mentioned, this setup is already laying the groundwork by leveraging refreshSubject, which can handle multiple queued requests.

I've implemented your suggestions with some changes which I will update the original question with. I think it is worth mentioning that let isRefreshing = false needs to be outside the scope of the implementation of HttpInterceptorFn exported or it will be false for every request. Is the expected behaviour that: while refresh is occurring other calls can be made (but will be retried after refresh as they will likely fail)?

The problem in your code is that the code in the subscribe is asynchoronous and the code below it is synchoronous, so that bottom code does not wait for the subject to have a value.

Instead try the below approach, where they use switchMap to refresh the token in a single stream (which eliminates this problem, since the switchMap will make the stream wait for the refresh observable) At the end of the stream, we again call the next(req) which restarts the API call or throw an error if the refresh token fails.
Make sure you call the refresh token only when the user is logged in this.storageService.isLoggedIn(), if they are unauthorized there is no need for the refresh logic.

You can use this tutorial from bezkoder which guides you on how to add the refreshToken logic.
Angular 12 Refresh Token with Interceptor and JWT example (chose the appropriate angular version from the links)
Bezkoder Github - http.interceptor.ts
export const jwtInterceptor: HttpInterceptorFn = (req, next) => {
  const router: Router = inject(Router);
  const authService: AuthService = inject(AuthService);
  let isRefreshing = false;
  req = req.clone({
    withCredentials: true,
  });

  const handle401Error = (isRefreshing: boolean, req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler) => {
    if (!isRefreshing) { // <- changed here!!!
      isRefreshing = true;
      if (this.storageService.isLoggedIn()) {
        return this.authService.refreshToken().pipe(
          switchMap(() => {
            isRefreshing = false;
            return next(req);
          }),
          catchError((error) => {
            isRefreshing = false;
            // if (error.status == '403') {
            //   this.eventBusService.emit(new EventData('logout', null));
            // }
            return throwError(() => error);
          })
        );
      }
    }
    return next(req);
  };

  return next(req).pipe(
    catchError((error) => {
      if (
        error instanceof HttpErrorResponse &&
        !req.url.includes('auth/signin') &&
        error.status === 401
      ) {
        return handle401Error(isRefreshing, req, next);
      }
      return throwError(() => error);
    })
  );
};


In the handle401error method did you mean  if (!isRefreshing)? I've implemented your suggestions and will update my questions with the results. However, now my refresh call is not being made at all (despite entering the method that makes the call). I believe return next(req) at the end of handle401error is being called and cancelling my refresh attempt first. I have placed comments to trace the flow and it looks like pipe() for authService.refreshToken() is never entered.

@AsadKoths There was a typo from my side could you check again, It should be if (!isRefreshing) {

I thought so and used that to begin with, the problems I described have been keeping the typo in mind.

@AsadKoths have you checked if it is going inside the if condition this.storageService.isLoggedIn(), try placing a console.log and checking

I have not implemented that condition. The code I actually have is updated in the original post. I do have a log inside authService.refreshToken() though, that is firing. It's just the actual http.post that is not getting completed.

@AsadKoths you are not returning the authService.refreshToken() that is why its not working, for my version of the answer

I tried it out and you're right, the lack of a return on that statement was the issue. I'm only keeping the other reply as the accepted answer at this point as it also solved the issue of resolving multiple requests in the future.

@AsadKoths No issues
